# I have a ground rod but I have no grounds in the house

Tags: electrical-panel, grounding

My panel is connected to the main water intake jumping the meter and I just installed an 8 foot copper ground rod. Even connecting a new breaker with only one outlet attached to it shows that I have no ground on the outlet. I've tested with two outlet testers and a multimeter. Any ideas to what I might be missing?

Comment: Is your house wired using ordinary NM cable (Romex), some sort of metal-sheathed/armored cable, or conduit of some flavor?  Was that "only one outlet" a newly installed homerun to the panel, or a new outlet on existing wiring?

Comment: The entire house is normal NM cable. The new outlet was one I added to test a single line as close to the panel as possible and to rule out any other wiring. It went straight from the panel three feet away to the outlet and that was all.

Comment: Did you connect the bare wire in the new NM cable you added to the ground bar in the panel and to the ground screw on the receptacle?

Comment: Yes, fully connected. Hot, neutral, and ground. It's not just this new outlet that has no ground, it's the entire house. I just used the new outlet to test without interference from other outlets or appliances. Sorry, My initial question wasn't super clear.

Comment: I'd post my standard answer of "Just hire a qualified electrician" again, but I'd probably get downvoted so I won't. But seriously, just hire a qualified electrician.

Comment: Can you check if there's continuity between your ground bus and neutral bus in your main panel?  I suspect they may not be properly bonded -- many cheap ground testers are really just testing for this connection.